# how to colour data according to factor in matrix scatterplot, in base R?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a matrix of scatterplots since i have many variables to compare with each other.

However, i am having issues with the colouring of the datapoints, using R base plots.

With GGplot2 everything seems fine, but when i move to base R then the colour coding is not working anymore. I know there is the possibility of using `pairs` but I still don't know how to color code.

Also, i have data with NA's and when i do get rid of those, the colour coding changes again, making the two base R plots not comparable. There must be something with the factors, i think but i can't work it out.

Here a working sample, with some examples.

EDIT: i am using the ggplot plot only as a reference to check for the colours of one of the "cells" in the scatterplot matrix.

```
library("scales")
library("ggplot2")

# load data and subset to simplify plotting
part_iris <- iris[c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ]

# select params to plot
params_to_plot <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")

# set factors
part_iris$Species <- factor(part_iris$Species, levels=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"))

# set seed to transform some (same) data into NA's
set.seed(131)

# transform into NA's
part_iris[sample(1:nrow(part_iris), 5), "Sepal.Length"] <- NA
part_iris[sample(1:nrow(part_iris), 5), "Sepal.Width"] <- NA
part_iris[sample(1:nrow(part_iris), 5), "Petal.Length"] <- NA
part_iris[sample(1:nrow(part_iris), 5), "Petal.Width"] <- NA

# create palette for each datapoint
species_palette <- hue_pal()(3)
names(species_palette) <- c("setosa", "viriginica", "versicolor")

# plot
dev.new()
ggplot(part_iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=Species)) + geom_point(size=5)

dev.new()
plot(part_iris[, params_to_plot], pch=21, cex=3, col="black", bg=species_palette, cex.axis=2, font=2)
legend(x="topright", legend=names(species_palette), col=species_palette, pch=21, xpd=T, ncol=3)

# now remove nas
no_nas_iris <- part_iris[complete.cases(part_iris), ]

# plot again
dev.new()
ggplot(no_nas_iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=Species)) + geom_point(size=5)

dev.new()
plot(no_nas_iris[, params_to_plot], pch=21, cex=3, col="black", bg=species_palette, cex.axis=2, font=2)
legend(x="topright", legend=names(species_palette), col=species_palette, pch=21, xpd=T, ncol=3)
```

Comment: Do `pt.bg=species_palette` instead of `col=species_palette`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `col` or `bg` in a base R plot you need to supply a vector corresponding to the colour for each point, not for each level.

So if you use:

`bg=species_palette[part_iris$Species]` instead of `bg=species_palette` you will get the behaviour you expect.  If you only use the palette vector it will simply recycle it along the dataset.  So (with some other fiddling to get the legend right):

```
pairs(part_iris[, params_to_plot], 
     pch=21, cex=3, 
     col="black", 
     bg=species_palette[part_iris$Species], 
     cex.axis=2, 
     font=2,
     oma=c(3,3,10,3)
     )
legend(x = "topright", 
       legend=names(species_palette), 
       pt.bg=species_palette,
       col="black",
       pt.cex=2,
       text.width = .1,
       pch=21, 
       xpd=T, 
       ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Great job using `oma` within `pairs` +1, I couldn't get it to work outside of that in `par()`.

Comment: yes, i had a very hard time with the legend, as well. thank you for providing such a great solution! i tried to do what you suggested (using the $), before posting, but maybe i got something wrong. i will try with my real data now.